# Send User Message to child window in CCtrlTab control

Tags: c++, winapi, messaging

I have a dialog window `(MainDlg : CDialogEx)`, in this window is tabcontrol `(MyTab : CTabCtrl)` and in this CTabCtrl I have child windows `(Tab1Dlg : CDialogEx)`. This "tab" windows is show or hidden according to tabs selection.
And I need to send message from MainDlg to TabDlg. How to do it?
Thanks for help.

Comment: May I ask whether my solution can solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

I used User messages. You can use [SendMessageA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagea) or  [SendMessageTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeouta) to send a User message to a child form.

**STEP 1.
Add user messages to pch.h or stdafx.h**

```
#define WM_USERMESSAGE  WM_APP+30
```

**STEP 2.
Add user message handlers Tab1Dlg.h before `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()`**

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

**STEP 3.
Add a macro to the Tab1Dlg.cpp file that accepts the message mapping**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Child_Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_USERMESSAGE, OnMyMessage)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Child_Dlg message handlers
LRESULT Child_Dlg::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(L"recv msg success");
    return 0;
}
```

**STEP 4.
Send the Msg in MainDlg**

```
//send msg to child wnd in tab control
void CMFCTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    //SendMessageA(m_childDlg.m_hWnd, WM_USERMESSAGE, 0, 0);

    DWORD result;
    SendMessageTimeout(m_childDlg.m_hWnd,
        WM_USERMESSAGE,
        0,
        0,
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG |
        SMTO_NORMAL,
        2000,
        &result);
}
```

Here is my test project and test gif;
https://github.com/SchrdingerCAT123/SendMsgToChild/tree/main/MFC_Test

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, it solved only half of the problem. It send message to child_01 or child_02. But I need to send a message to all tabs-windows. All tabs windows is founded on base class CTabChildDialog....

Comment: You only need to modify the handle of tabs-windows used in SendMessageTimeout to send messages to the desired CTabChildDialog.

Comment: You mean, I must do it for each window. We have not a method, how to send it to all CTabChildDialogs...

Comment: `WM_USER + x` is the wrong range to use. You'll want to go with `WM_APP + x` instead. It's a mystery what sort of *"security"* you hope to gain from a call to [`SendMessageTimeoutA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeouta). The documentation **explicitly** states that the timeout will be ignored here. It's also a mystery how you'd use `HWND_BROADCAST` to send a message to a child window.